# interpolate rails expression in slim javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am interpolating an array in slim JavaScript:

```
javascript:
  values2 = #{facet.map{|v| [type[0].html_safe,v[1]]}}
```

In the browser it gives me this error:
Uncaugh SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

Because the rendered strings are rendered this way:

```
values = [[&quot;Agency&quot;, 3301], [&quot;Agency&quot;, 225], [&quot;Agency&quot;, 63]];
```

How can this be done properly?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way

```
          javascript:
            values = #{facet.map{|v| [v[0], v[1]]}.to_s.html_safe};
```